# В целях безопасности

Tags: лексика, жаргон

«В целях безопасности не отвлекайте водителя!» Что за цели? Разве не безопасность и есть та самая цель?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что "в целях" в подобных фразах употребляется в значении предлога. *Для* безопасности. Да, вот такой канцеляризм. Вряд ли уместный в маршрутке, но зато краткий! Как сказать короче?

Comment: А какой смысл в краткости? В салоне автобуса текст, произнесённый профессиональным голосом, крутят раза три за 15 минут, спокойно едем, колёса крутятся. Краткость нужна в экстренных ситуациях.

Comment: Не знаю, какой смысл, но тенденция к укорачиваниям слов и предложений в языках есть. А чтоб это голосом произносилось, никогда не слышал. Висит себе объява, и все.

Comment: Будете по нашему Нахимовскому проезжать, услышите.

Answer (score 0):

Согласен, канцеляризмы — это бич нашего общества. Но уже привычный и даже необходимый.
"Не нарушайте правила безопасности — не отвлекайте водителя!"
"Не отвлекайте водителя — берегите свою жизнь!"
И наконец, классическое:
"Хлопнешь дверью — умрёшь на месте!"
:)

Comment: За такую классику могут отправить на скамейку запасных.

Comment: Надеюсь, простят на первый раз. Я тут человек новый.

Comment: Спокойно. Это про водителей маршруток и их листовки. Хотя время частников уже прошло.

Answer (score 0):

> В Целях — предл. с род. Употребляется при указании на общую целевую
>   направленность действия и соответствует по значению сл.: для чего
>   либо, с какой либо целью. Толковый словарь Ефремовой. Т. Ф. Ефремова.
>   2000 …   Современный толковый словарь русского языка Ефремовой

Можно спорить, насколько оно уместно в контексту, но само по себе выражение "в целях" я бы к таким уж канцеляризмам, тем более - предлогам, не относил.

Comment: >> *В Целях — **предл**. с род ... (Современный толковый словарь русского языка Ефремовой). ...но само по себе выражение "в целях" я бы... к предлогам не относил* И это как?

Answer (score 0):

У безопасности не одна цель, и мероприятие это комплексное.
Не повредить, предостеречь, уберечь, предотвратить, спасти (жизнь), как себе, так и другим людям, вовлечённым в ситуацию и действие. Так что всё верно.

Comment: Цель объявления в автобусе — предостеречь, информируя. Это одно из мероприятий. Мероприятий много, а цель у них одна.